# How to check if an object with an ID already exists on the page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an “exists” function for jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

Say for instance you have the div:

```
<div id="hello"></div>
```

And you are dynamically creating a div:

```
<div id="hello"></div>
```

Is there a function you can use in Jquery which will check to see if the object with the ID you are trying to create already exists on the page?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For jQuery method you could go with

```
if($("#selector").length) {
    //object already exists
}
```

Comment: simple, great. this works perfectly

Answer (score 15):

```
if (document.getElementById('hello')) {
    // yup, already there
}
```

Or, the jQuery way:

```
if ($('#hello').length) {
    // yup, already there
}
```

Comment: Even shorter: `($('#hello')[0])`

Comment: If you are creating multiple elements before you add them to the page, you can give them the same id with this check. An element can have an id but will not be found with document.getElementById until it is part of the document.

Comment: +1 nice to see both option mentioned here